# Set bitmap as drawableLeft to EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am developing an app that retrieves contact image from contact database and set it to EditText as drawableLeft along with contact name

I am able to retrieve name as well as contact image as bitmap, but not able to set it as drawableLeft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting bitmap on textview use ImageView

Comment: I want to show image as well as name in edittext , so that user can edit text

Comment: yes it good to edit contact number in edittext but it looks weird if you want image in edittext to get edit.If you want to change the image of contact person even then you can use imageview and on click of imageview you can open camera or gallery

Comment: yeah , this is a great idea ..Let me try it

Answer (score 7):

Try this code:

```
BitmapDrawable drawableLeft = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), yourBitmap);
mYourEditText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawableLeft, null, null, null);
```

Comment: drawableLeft --- is " int " , not bitmap , hence I am facing the problem

Comment: Try the code above. It creates a drawable from the bitmap and sets the drawable as drawableLeft.